# Is there a complete tutorial on setting up a Squid on pfSense as a remotely accessible proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid, pfsense

I have a pfSense box that I'd like to add squid to to use as a proxy that I can use remotely. I have installed squid, but I can't figure out what firewall or other settings I need to change to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The only specific configuration I can think of is allowing any IP to connect to your squid proxy. In "Proxy server", you have the "Access control" tab. You can put 0.0.0.0/0  and see if that helps.

If it doesn't help, you're going to want to create a specific rule in your firewall to allow access to squid. This should look like allow any to *squidIP* on tcp *squidport* on interface WAN.

That should do the trick.